# .Net Ef Core: I don't want to throw data into multiple tables at once

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I set up a database with ef core code first management. I have two related tables.I want to insert data into a table. but since it has a relationship with the other table, it tries to throw data into the other table. whereas I only want to record a table. how do i do this?

code:

> 1. table

```
  public class JobTable
        {
            [Key]
            public int ID_JOB { get; set; }
            public JobType JobType { get; set; }
            public string JOB_KEY { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan JOB_TIME { get; set; }
            public int? DAY { get; set; }
            public Boolean IS_ACTIVE { get; set; }
            public string? DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
            public CustomUser CustomUser { get; set; }
        }
```

> 2. table:

```
public class JobType
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID_JOB_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string JOB_TYPE_NAME { get; set; }
        public List<JobTable> jobTable { get; set; }
    }
```

> ef code:

```
  context.JobTable.Add(jobTable);
            
  context.SaveChanges();
```

i just want to add data to 'jobtable' table. but it tries to throw data into the 'jobtype' table as well, since it is related to the 'jobtype' table. idont want this. how can I do it?

Comment: You omitted the important part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way that you define the `JobTable` will also create a new record for `JobType` when inserting the `JobTable` record.

Instead, modify the `JobTable` to apply a foreign key property (`JobTypeId`) to define a relationship to the `JobType` table.

```cs
public class JobTable
{
    ...

    public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual JobType JobType { get; set; }

}

public class JobType
{
    ...

    public ICollection<JobTable> JobTables { get; set; }
}
```

During inserting the new `JobTable` record, you need to provide the `JobType`'s `Id` into the entity data to be inserted.

---

**Reference**

[One-to-Many Relationship Conventions in Entity Framework Core (Convention 4)](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)

Comment: Hello. if i do as you say it will create two columns. generates both 'jobId' and 'jobtypeid_jobtype'. Shouldn't it normally be a single column?

Comment: The `JobType` class needs to amend as well for the `JobTables` property. And try to regenerate the `JobTable` table.